# How to synchronize local SQL database with a server to provide it to mobile or other devices?

Tags: python, json, linux, synchronization, data-synchronization

I've created a software (in Python), which is tracking time of my projects I am working on. This software is generally on my PC, but now I have a copy on my laptop, too.

The problem is, I can't get them in sync, but I wish to have a server, which will have all data and that a client can get the deltas. But how does this work? I have no idea what I have to do on a server, because I most likely code on the client side.

- Should the server receive only the new data as JSONs?
- How does a client know, which data was already requested to avoid overhead?
- Which programming language can be used (e.g. Python) to have a secure back-end?
- Can it be used for future apps on mobile or websites, too?
- If other software is involved, it should be open source and it should be for Linux (not Windows)

I know that it might have something to do with creating my own REST API, but how? What are modern frameworks/languages for it?

I am thankful for any tip, which nudges me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

> This software is generally on my PC, but now I have a copy on my laptop, too. The problem is, I can't get them in sync

How does the software store the data? File? sqlite DB?

> Should the server receive only the new data as JSONs?

Depends on how you build the tracking software and the server, if the server accepts connections directly to database (e.g. a MySQL server with open ports) you could just have your software connect to it and read/write directly, or you could also create a REST API that you call when you want to read/write to the DB.

> How does a client know, which data was already requested to avoid overhead?

Timestamps or primary key IDs, this also depends on how you build the software/DB, if you have something like a table `tracking` with a single column `time` which has 1 row per project and that's it then you don't need to keep track of any requests, just update the column if your value is higher than the current stored value.

> Which programming language can be used (e.g. Python) to have a secure back-end?

This is up to you and what you're familiar with. (As for security, even the most secure oriented language can be as insecure as a door locked with a seweing thread if configured incorrectly)

> Can it be used for future apps on mobile or websites, too?

Don't understand this question but yes.

> If other software is involved, it should be open source and it should be for Linux (not Windows)

Also yes.